# Transform existing ETL to Azure

Tags: azure, etl, data-warehouse

I have a general question. Imagine we have a working ETL, regardless of its type (SSI, ODI, etc.), what are the best options to transform this existing working ETL to the Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Azure Architecture Center? This one discusses a hybrid ETL with existing on-premises SSIS and Azure Data Factory (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/data/hybrid-etl-with-adf).

Comment: Yes, I have seen this one before. This is a Hybrid system, I want to know if is there is a chance to transform an existing ETL on-premise, to the Azure?